# Database connection - best practice

Tags: h2

I'd like to know what is the best practice to connect to H2 database when using embedded mode, e.g. in standalone Java desktop application.

Currently, I have the database file (.h2) in the same directory as main application jar file and using standard **jdbc:h2:file:** prefix to locate the file on the disc. Of course, this can be portable only if you can get the absolute path of the file dynamically, i.e. as relative path to the main Jar.

I am using this:

```
class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

and its working. But I am not sure if its completely portable. I didn't try it on all the OS that Java supports.

Is there any other (maybe better) way to do this?

Regards,
Lubos

Comment: Recently, I came to this topic again and found solution. I posted solution on my starting computer blog here: http://lubosplavucha.com/2013/08/30/java_portable_database/

Comment: your comment link is dead - would you mind updating it or answering fully here?